# How to convert Ajax to Mobile Friendly Script/Jquery

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile, mobile

My site using Ajax to display the drop down model fields
When checked in mobile browser, due to ajax technology not supported by most mobile phones, the drop down model field does not appear and remain stagnant

Is there any way to change script to mobile friendly technology so that when someone views the page through mobile, the script can use that mobile friendly script

thnx

Answer (score 0):

`ajax` not supported in mobile?? It is supported in major Operating systems such as iOS and Android.

I hope you are not programming for some old mobile browsers.

You can simply utilize the `ajax` functions in jQuery Mobile. I'm doing it for many of my projects.

A simple ajax call would look like below

```
$.ajax({            
 type: "POST",
 url: url,
 data: param,
 contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
 dataType: "json",
 success: successFunc,
 error: errorFunc,
 beforeSend:function(){$.mobile.loading( 'show' );},
 complete:function(){$.mobile.loading( 'hide');}
});
```

Comment: Sure thanks, let me try it out.. Actually, i tested the site in dudamobile and some other sites which says to convert it to mobile friendly, there due to ajax, i was not seeing the drop down menu in there browsers. Was wondering why so?